# Why was question 20155337 deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions, moderators

Question here:

[Why is this query slow the first time after I start the service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20155337)

tl;dr:  After about an hour, someone swung by and started editing and answering and whatnot, as one does.  Pretty immediately after that, [Bill the Lizard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1288/bill-the-lizard) summarily insta-deleted the whole thing, no reason given.

I only saw this just now, about four hours after posting, having had other matters to attend to and previously having experienced that one often doesn't get much by then anyway.

Can someone shed some light on why my question was banished by the fist of an angry god?

---

Further info for us sub-10K plebs:  it was a question about very puzzling SQL Server query behavior and how to iron it out.

Comment: And your question was about what? Add some info about your question to your post, so it's easier to comment. Offtopic question maybe?

Comment: While the question itself isn't a great question, I don't see anything glaringly wrong with it that would cause a mod to insta-delete it. So either it was a mistake or there's something going on behind the scenes that I can't see.

Comment: Yeah, this looks like an honest mistake. I'm sure a mod will look into it shortly

Comment: The only thing I can see is that maybe it's because of the cursing. This is supposed to be a *professional* resource of knowledge, not a place to vent. With that said, I wouldn't have outright deleted your post as it wasn't that bad; I would have instead just fixed the title and edited the first sentence to clean it up and then left a comment letting you know why I edited.

Comment: Errr…  Cursing??

Comment: *"Why the hell does this SQL Server query run forever the first time [...]"* | *"What the hell is going on here?"*

Comment: Yes... cursing... I mean, we talk like that at work sometimes when it's just a few close colleagues... but that's the difference between the spoken word, something that fades away quickly, versus the *published* word, which thousands of future visitors would see for years to come...

Comment: I was unaware the denizens of this fine establishment were of such tender sensibilities as to deem that particular epithet for the underworld so antithetical to proper discourse.  Ahem.

Comment: lol, well, again, what we do offline, *(or in the C++ Lounge chat room)*, is much different than how we want to present Stack Overflow to the world. :D

Comment: Keep in mind, @atario, that only the first line or so of a question (combined with its title) are shown in the normal questions lists and moderator queues. And you managed to make *both* of these read as though you'd written a rant instead of a question. Lesson learned, I hope.

Comment: Just FTR: While I don't see "hell" as offensive in any way (unprofessional, but not offensive), I would have voted to close your initial version of the question as being nothing but a rant. IMO, it wasn't so much a question as it was a venting session. Perhaps you should tone down the rhetoric and unnecessary **bold** emphasis and concentrate more on asking a clearly stated *question* that we can answer at SO.

Comment: I don't get how looking for an explanation/solution to a weird situation (and doing so in an engaging fashion) constitutes a rant and not a question.  And if you'll notice, one of the *few* things bolded was the actual question.

Comment: @shog9:  are you implying that the mods insta-delete without even opening the question?  Tsk, tsk.

Comment: The (probably) canonical discussion^Wconvention^Wknock-down-drag-out fight about "naughty" words is [Is the language brainf ck offensive?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/24079), @Atario. Speaking as someone for whom the answer to that question is _emphatically_ "No", I still prefer the version of your title without "hell". I think the word was just a distraction.

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't consider this a matter of "tender sensibilities", but of standards and preferences. Although I'm fine with the undelete after the edit, I appreciate and agree with @BilltheLizard's decision to delete in the first place.

Comment: So hang on.  Are we not allowed to refer to "DLL Hell" in titles and lead sentences?  And where are these rules listed?

Comment: @Atario - Yeah, but luckily there isn't just one Uber-Mod , rather a bevy of mods. mods VS mos

Comment: @Atario - Big difference there.. come on, surely you recognize that language is a slimy beast

Comment: @Atario: yes, absolutely. Not saying that's what happened in this case - I can't know - but, yeah, all the time. Wasting time on page-loads for spam, non-answers and assorted noise is not really practical on a site the size of Stack Overflow. If you start off your question with "Full Movies Streaming Live HD" it would probably be deleted unread as well.

Comment: @Atario: Not saying looking for explanation/solution is wrong. I'm saying the way you asked the question made it appear more like a rant than an explanation/solution question. There's a vast difference between "WTF? This is #&$&@^ BS!!!" and "Can someone help me understand?" are pretty clear. If you ask your question in a clear fashion instead of resorting to the rhetoric and noise, it's more clear that you're asking an actual, technical question instead of just complaining about something. SO is supposed to be a technical site - don't be surprised if rant-like posts get unexpectedly closed.

Comment: @KenWhite:  There is a vast difference between those two things, yes, but that has nothing to do with my question which was neither of those but rather "this is bewildering and bizarre and can anyone talk me down?".

Comment: @Atario: The problem is it's very hard to tell given that it's possible to use the same set of words and phrases to express two quite different emotions and mindsets.

Comment: @Atario - Ah , rest on it buddy. All is well

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn:  exactly why I always consider it best policy to give the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: @Atario: Not to a moderator (or an initial view by someone else, like me) of the title and beginning of your original question. If it appears to be a rant from the title, and reads like a rant at the start, and keeps looking like a rant when you read, it's probably a rant. Post a less rant-like question, and you won't have that problem. Benefit of the doubt is fine, but even with that being given, I would have voted to close your initial post. Accept the constructive criticism, and phrase your questions better in the future (or accept them being canned sometimes when you don't). :)

Comment: @KenWhite:  Sorry, maybe I'm intensely stupid or something, but I'm not seeing how anything about that was rant-like aside from the actual "the hell"s (of which one was actually self-deprecating, no one seems to have pointed out).  I mean:  I gave illustrative code, I explained what the problem was, I showed that I had tried some things to investigate on my own before running here to ask, and so forth.  Really, the sense I'm getting here is that the site's "culture" is far more interested in its image than in actually helping people with actual problems…  :/

Comment: Look man, we're all just trying to help you *here*. The question shouldn't have been deleted - it was edited and restored. But if we didn't try to convince you to leave off the noise, we'd just end up back here in another month doing this again - no one wants that.

Comment: I'm not saying I don't appreciate all the discussion.  It's exactly what the site should be for.  But I'm just saying that encouraging *deletions* based on snap judgements is probably not the best of ideas.  And I am seeing a lot of that sentiment here.

Comment: Even though I don't like repeating myself, I'm going to intentionally do so now: *Accept the constructive criticism, and phrase your questions better in the future (or accept them being canned sometimes when you don't).* It really doesn't matter what you can see - what matters is what the readers of your question see when you post on SO. If you don't want constructive help, keep posting questions like that, have them deleted/downvoted/closed, and then we can do this again. :-)

Comment: Here's what you're saying:  "you're wrong for writing something in a way that he misread it.".  Here's what I'm saying:  "maybe read a little closer before insta-delete?".  But I guess I'm not allowed to give constructive criticism, and may only take it.  Message received.

Comment: @Atario: No, that's not what I'm saying at all. :-) I agree that someone read it, wrongly thought it was offensive, and flagged it, and it was deleted as a result. I'm also saying that, when I look at the original question, **I would have voted to close it** as a rant instead of a question. I didn't find it offensive, but it appears like a venting session for the most part. The constructive part is that maybe if you phrase your questions differently, that erroneous flag (or the close vote I would have made) might be avoided in the future.

Comment: @Atario: Again, intentionally repeating myself, I said as much in my [first comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208651/why-was-question-20155337-deleted#comment665886_208651) to this post as well.

Comment: Yes, you've said you would have voted thus several times, while not once acknowledging that that would have been the wrong thing to do.  One must therefore surmise that you think voting to close based on incorrect assessments of surface appearance is correct.

Comment: @Atario: No. Once again you're putting words in my mouth I didn't say. I said *your question was written in a way that would have received a downvote from me, because it appeared to be a rant*. I don't agree it would have been wrong to do so. I don't know how to state it more clearly than that, as I have several times now. If you don't want that in the future, don't post questions that appear to be nothing but rants. We're spinning wheels here. I keep explaining, and you keep ignoring what I'm saying. I'll not waste more (of both of our) time here. Good luck. :-)

Comment: Then maybe I'm overinterpreting your consistent use of "appear to be".  You actually think what I wrote was *in fact* a rant, and not a solicitation for help at all?  Even now, having thoroughly gone over it?  In that case I'm not sure what to tell you.  Because it clearly was the latter.  It explained a premise and asked for a solution.  There's hardly a better definition of a question than that.

Comment: @Atario: No, you're not overinterpreting anything. *Appears to be* is the relevant information. If you write what **appears to be** a rant, it will most likely be closed/downvoted. Your task is to write a question that **does not appear to be** a rant. If you ask a question that is clearly a question, it won't be confusing to everyone else. Again, **I don't know how to state this more clearly**. If you write what **looks like a rant**, **reads like a rant**, and then narrowly avoids **being a rant** at the end, it will probably **appear to be a rant** to those who read it.

Comment: Then the fact that you place no blame with the voter but only the writer must mean that you are arguing that it is proper to act on appearance and not truth.  There's no other possible conclusion.

Comment: @Atario: Once again, you are stating *facts* not in evidence. I'm stating that it is the **writer's responsibility** to present the proper meaning to **the reader**, and that should be clear to everyone. If the **writer** can't express their meaning or intent clearly, it's not the **reader's** fault.

Comment: @Atario Reading through this: you're misunderstanding what people are communicating (occasionally quite profoundly). You are also being fairly hostile. I strongly suggest you leave this be for now and come back later - your emotions on this issue are getting the better of you.

Comment: @Jonathan Hobbs: No, no, no, no, no. You've got it all wrong. He's just being *assertive*, not *aggressive*.

Comment: @BoltClock I didn't say aggressive! Hostility doesn't have to come with aggression.

Comment: @Jonathan Hobbs: I know, I was deliberately evading the point in favor of making a play on words ;)

Comment: I'm not being hostile, nor aggressive, nor even assertive.  I'm merely stating what I'm observing.  Facts, as confirmed by everyone else here:  (1) the question should not have been deleted; (2) it was right to undelete it.  Despite these facts, certain people persist in telling me *I* am somehow the party to blame.  Go figure.

Answer (score 32):

Your question was flagged as offensive. You sounded incredibly pissed off (especially in the original title, before it was edited). That didn't really help matters — while your irate tone didn't contain anything *offensive* by the usual definition of the word, on the surface, from the mod queue it probably looked like you didn't have a serious question to ask and were just ranting.

Keep in mind that, like humans, lizards make mistakes too; this was probably a lapse in Bill's judgement. As a unicorn, infallible unlike humans and reptiles, I agree that your question didn't actually meet our definition of "offensive" and shouldn't have been deleted on those grounds. So I've undeleted it (and it looks like someone else has edited the cruft out for you as well).

Comment: Thanks for the enlightenment. I never realized that unicorns were infallible. It all makes sense now!

Comment: Cornets are cooler

Comment: I didn't consider the tone irate at all.  *Bewildered* was the intent and actual emotion, in fact.

Comment: Oh, and:  shouldn't something, *somewhere* say what was wrong?  Instead of just silent questionicide?

Comment: @Atario: Oh, definitely - this comes up all the time and we're hoping to find a way to address it. Here's one discussion - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193789/give-moderators-the-option-to-select-a-deletion-reason-when-removing-posts

Comment: +1 for `like humans, lizards make mistakes too`.

Answer (score 3):

Ah, you rubbed a mod the wrong way buddy(probably the title).  One thing about SO is that we do pride ourselves on being the anti-Reddit, communication-wise. The line:

> What the hell is going on here?  I feel like I'm taking crazy pills!

Is certainly hilarious in its own right, ...buuut it doesn't quite fit in this culture. It's OK , part of the education. We do like well-placed dry-humor(nerdy LOL's = Kosher), we do.. so yeah. ANYWAY, congrats on the 2nd life there.

But I have to echo Jmort et al, substantively it's a good post. In general, err on the side of caution with humor. *Especially* in the title(you don't want to give a bad 1st impression)

There's an fAQ that outlines what questions to avoid - here's a list of  'em - https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

In the end, you *do* have the option to re-submit it. Try to make an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: You aren't a 10k user.. you didn't see the question, did you ?

Comment: If a mod insta-deletes a post, it's probably better to know why before reposting.

Comment: @JoshC - Nah I didn't see it. curious tho ;-)

Comment: @Mysticial - This insta-delete feature is intriguing .. so how does one get such supapowers!! Its a bit scary nonetheless

Comment: I'd repost the whole question here for you, but it feels like that would be rather frowned upon, considering.

Comment: @Adel Post was [undeleted by BoltClock](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20155337/revisions), there was nothing seemingly wrong with it.. as your answer implies.

Comment: @JoshC - touche, I'll eat the humble pie this time.

Comment: You could edit and add more information Abel, now that we sort of have a better idea of why it was deleted and why it was subsequently undeleted....

Comment: I don't like the `...buuut it doesn't quite fit in this culture` part. Shouldn't stack overflow be open to people from different cultures? If some posts are written in a different style than others, shouldn't that be considered inspirational as long as they're not offensive?

Comment: @user68958 - yes, granted.

Answer (score -13):

Question resurrected by the good Mr. "BoltClock's a Unicorn". Huzzah!

Consensus (but not including the insta-deleting party himself) seems to indicate that the problem was that people are truly, *deeply* offended by the word…uh…well, I guess I can't say it.  Never mind!

Comment: If you peruse stackoverflow questions, you will be hard pressed to find *any* questions with hell in them. nothing persnal

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hell reports "12,863 results" as of this writing.   3,230 results for http://stackoverflow.com/search?q="the+hell" .

Comment: If folks had been *deeply offended*, the question would've been *locked* and you'd have had a 100 point penalty applied to your account. Instead, it was merely deleted.

Comment: @Atario - I had queried that too... and was debating my comment. But intuitively, it's rare. keep in mind - 6,140,689 total stack questions.

Comment: @JoshC:  your comment has an unnecessary "or not" and "just", and either "unnecessary" or "noise".  These are noise and not beneficial to the comment.  Please revise or I shall grow rather cross with you indeed!

Comment: *Sigh*.  My actual point there was that if we're going to go around rewarding and encouraging nitpicking, we're not going to have anything but an endless circlejerk of who can be the most nitpicky.  That and a gradually dwindling supply of actual non-deleted content on which to nitpick.

Comment: I think it has been made clear enough that this was a mistaken deletion, and using the word "hell" is not usually grounds for such an action and nobody is "deeply offended" by it. But it made your question *look* like it was a rant, and somebody cast a flag - because with x million visitors every day, *somebody* is going to be offended by *something*. It was that unfortunate combination that brought about a lapse in judgement, that has now been corrected

Comment: @JoshC:  Deleting your comment was exactly what I *didn't* want…  -_-